# What does Alpha Strike mean

Tags: terminology, hawken

I've seen this term pop up in the forums and in game, but I was taking a break from Hawken and now I am confused. From what I gather it's a special type of attack or something.

I couldn't find a description of it in the forums either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alpha strike in video games typically means an all out attack using every available weapon.  This is done early in the fight in an attempt to cripple or completely destroy an enemy before they have a chance to launch their attack.

In Hawken terms:

> An alpha strike is delivering all of your damage at once, typically firing your primary, your secondary, and using your item all at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

It refers to firing all of your available weapons at once - I believe this term dates back to the old MechWarrior games, where there was usually a single key that would fire every weapon at once, frequently with disastrous consequences for both your target and yourself.

Comment: The term dates back to the Vietnam War - it's US naval jargon for unloading an aircraft carrier's worth of planes (and associated ordinance) in a rapid assault.